# What are the energy levels responsible for CdSe's fluorescence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-chemistry, fluorescence

Fluorescence is when a material absorbs photons of one wavelength and radiate photons of another wavelength (necessarily lower due to conservation of energy, assuming the material is unchanged).

CdSe quantum dots fluoresce bright visible colours under UV light. The energy of the visible light increases with the exciton energy. The band gap energy of the semiconductor is slightly higher than the exciton energy.

Is the mechanism for fluorescence that UV light is absorbed to excite electrons to the band gap -> they form excitons -> excitons annihilate and emit radiation of higher wavelength than the absorbed UV? If not, what energy transitions are responsible?

Comment: Seems pretty much correct, plus or minus needing excitons to form in the first place - direct electron-hole recombination should be a part of it. Your favorite visible LED material will fluoresce just fine as well (you may need to remove the plastic packaging to get much UV in to it...).

Comment: @JonCuster  But if UV is needed to excite electrons to conduction band, surely UV is emitted from direct electron-hole recombination?

Comment: UV is well above the band gap for bulk CdSe. So, you put electrons far up in to the conduction band, they rapidly thermalize down to the band edges, and you get emission from the exciton and un-bound (but at the band edge) recombination. Shining UV on just makes sure that your source is well away from any emission, making either real spectroscopy or a gee-whiz eyeball demonstration that much easier.